# ETH and tokens sent mistakenly to an LP pair, can they be recovered?

Tags: uniswap

so by mistake of my factory contract, it sent the token and ETH to the token uniswap v2 LP pair.

here is the lp pair contract: 0x6ee8924a4297f7dfdda32f4c8cc02688873a8c05

can they be recovered?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not posting this issue in a public forum. Obviously, if there's a public method to withdraw ETH, many individuals may withdraw their funds before you do!

You can find the minted LP tokens at this address: 0x1277213f30d6895b6a540c7dd3edc6d94a1f583a, which has not public source code!

If you're able to withdraw them from 0x1277213f30d6895b6a540c7dd3edc6d94a1f583a, you can easily access the ETHs. If not, there may be no other way to get ETHs because the reserve value in the LP contract is the same as the balance like other normal LP contracts.